# SQL/POSTGRESSQL trying to group by value 2 diffrent tables and then join them any ideas?

Tags: javascript, sql, inner-join, union, postgresql-9.1

im trying to get a new table from two diffrent tables: retweet,likes. The new table need to include columns such as post_id, retweet_count and likes_count
I tried to use SQL queries like this.

```
SELECT post_id,COUNT(post_id) as retweet_count
FROM retweet
GROUP BY post_id -------> which give me the retweet_count
UNION
SELECT post_id, COUNT(post_id) as likes_count
FROM likes
GROUP BY post_id; -------> which give me the likes_count
```

The result i'm trying to get is like this:

```
post_id|retweet_count|likes_count|
1         2            0
2         2            2
3         0            3
```

the new table that i get includes only post_id,retweet_count columns and it add the like_count data as a new row instead of a new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the subqueries together:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT post_id,COUNT(post_id) as retweet_count
      FROM retweet
      GROUP BY post_id -------> which give me the retweet_count
     ) r FULL JOIN
     (SELECT post_id, COUNT(post_id) as likes_count
      FROM likes
      GROUP BY post_id -------> which give me the likes_count
     ) l
     USING (post_id);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon you know maybe how to translaste it to knex library queries?

Comment: @Madhacker . . . No, I do not.  The question is tagged "sql" and "postgres", and this is a SQL solution.